# Python Pandas - Counting the number of preceding rows or values before a change in value occured

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, vectorization

I have the following df and the desired output I seek is column "Days_Out".

| Name_ID | Date | Out_In | Change | Form_Req | Days Out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 01/01/2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1001 | 02/01/2022 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1001 | 03/01/2022 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1001 | 04/01/2022 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1001 | 05/01/2022 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 1001 | 06/01/2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1001 | 07/01/2022 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1001 | 08/01/2022 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Anytime the "Form_Req" column is 1, I want to count the number of preceding 1's in the "Out_In" column before it changes back to 0. I'm looking for a vectorized solution as I have >1M rows and for loop would be extremely slow.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: It would help if you showed the desired output in this example.

Answer (score 0):

I voluntarily used Numpy in the following like you want something fast and optimized for calculus.

You should certainly find pandas functions to achieve that but numpy is faster.

**So let's go :)**

Numpy function `np.argwhere` gives indices where arrays elements are non-zeros ie in our case `1`

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name_ID': [1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001], 
                   'Date': ["01/01/2022", "02/01/2022", "03/01/2022", "04/01/2022", 
                            "05/01/2022", "06/01/2022", "07/01/2022", "08/01/2022"], 
                   'Out_In': [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], 
                   'Change': [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], 
                   'Form_Req': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                   'Days Out': [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1],
                   })

start = time.time()
pos = list(np.argwhere(np.array(df['Form_Req'])).squeeze())

cnt = [df['Out_In'][start:end].sum() for (start, end) in zip([0]+pos[:-1], pos)]

end = time.time() 

print("pos : ", pos)
print("cnt : ", cnt)

print(" speed : ", end-start)
```

Print indices (pos) and count (cnt)

```
pos :  [4, 7]
cnt :  [3, 1]
speed :  0.0004115104675292969 # Pretty fast indeed
```

could be read as this :

- 3 X `1` between 0 and 4 indices
- 1 X `1` between 4 and 7 indices

**If you want to have it in the form of a dataframe :**

```py
r = df.iloc[pos].copy()
r['count'] = cnt

print(r)
```

```
   Name_ID        Date  Out_In  Change  Form_Req  Days Out  count
4     1001  05/01/2022       0       1         1         3      3
7     1001  08/01/2022       0       1         1         1      1
```

**Another technique to put the count (cnt) directly in df :**

```py
diff = np.diff([0]+pos) # = array([4, 3])

prefix = [0]
suffix = ((len(df)-1) - pos[-1]) * [0]

values = prefix + list( np.concatenate([np.pad([cnt[p[0]] ], (p[1]-1,0), 'constant') \
                                        for p in enumerate(diff)]) )

if len(suffix) > 0:
    values += suffix

df['count'] = values
```

```
   Name_ID        Date  Out_In  Change  Form_Req  Days Out  count
0     1001  01/01/2022       0       0         0         0      0
1     1001  02/01/2022       1       1         0         0      0
2     1001  03/01/2022       1       0         0         0      0
3     1001  04/01/2022       1       0         0         0      0
4     1001  05/01/2022       0       1         1         3      3
5     1001  06/01/2022       0       0         0         0      0
6     1001  07/01/2022       1       1         0         0      0
7     1001  08/01/2022       0       1         1         1      1
```

Comment: Adding this for robustness in the case that last value in Days Out is not equal to 1....  

`if pos[-1] != len(df)-1:
        cnt.append(0)
        diff = np.append(diff, len(df)-pos[-1]-1)`

Comment: I inspired myself from your comment and I have introduced a prefix and a suffix